# How many non-isomorphic partial orders of a certain size?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm working on the consistency of Martin's axiom and I need some help counting.  Assume we are in a universe where GCH holds and $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal.  How many non-isomorphic partial orders are there of size less than $\kappa$.  I think the answer is $\kappa$ (indeed this is what Jech writes) and can convince myself, but it is not very clear to me how to systematically count the number of different partial orders of a certain size.

Let me know if I need to give more context, I'm asking my specific question in a general way.

Comment: hmm I think I figured it out.  I beleive the way to do it is by counting possible chains (and thinking of them as subsets).  I'd still like an expert to explain it clearly.

Comment: I'm far from an expert, but I hope my answer explains it clearly.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $(P,\le)$ is a partial order and $|P|<\kappa$. We can embed every such $P$ in its power set, using $p\in P$ then $p\mapsto\{x\in P\mid x\le p\}$. If we assume GCH then without loss of generality $P=\lambda<\kappa$ then $P(\lambda)=\lambda^+\le\kappa$.

Now we have that every partial order of cardinality less than $\kappa$ can be embedded into its power set, which is at most $\kappa$.

Note that *every* possible partially ordered set can be embedded this way into its power set, thus:

1. If $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal (and of course regular) every power set is smaller, the number of partially ordered sets is at most $\lambda^+$ for $\lambda<\kappa$, and thus we have $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$ many partially ordered sets of size $<\kappa$.
2. If $\kappa=\mu^+$ is a successor cardinal (thus regular assuming choice) then every partially ordered set can be embedded in $P(\mu)=\kappa$ - by GCH - and so there are only $\kappa$ many of those.

Comment: yes thank you. I have a follow-up question.  I'll ask soon.

Comment: I am just heading to bed, so I'll only see that much later. I hope it's fine.

Comment: I believe you have an upper bound.  A lower bound is the number of linear orders which is the same as the upper bound.

Comment: @Erin: Yeah, in the case of successor cardinal you can think of it as an upper bound; the lower bound is trivially achieved. Fix one order type for $\mu$ and then every permutation of $\mu$ defines a new partially ordered set; there are $\mu^+=\kappa$ many of those.